# How install the ClosedXML NuGet

Tags: closedxml

I'm trying to install ClosedXML NuGet in an ASP / VB.NET project that uses .NET Framework 4.0, and I'm getting the following error:

[image]

What do I need to do for ClosedXML be installed OK in my project?

Thanks in advance,

Marcelo Camarate

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest installing using the Package Manager Console.

You can find this in `Tools> Nugget Package Manager > Package Manager Console`

Once that's up, paste this `Install-Package ClosedXML`and hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

Try to installing the latest NuGet Package Manager.

After the installation, restart Visual Studio.

Link for download the latest version of NuGet:

https://www.nuget.org/downloads